# bundle state is installed/ couldnt reslove imported packages- AEM 6.2

Tags: maven, service, osgi, bundle, aem-6

I have installed maven bundle into http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles
but the bundle state is installed. The error with imported packages is as follows:

jersey.repackaged.jsr166e,version=[2.22,3) -- Cannot be resolved
okhttp3 -- Cannot be resolved
okhttp3.internal -- Cannot be resolved
okhttp3.logging -- Cannot be resolved
okio -- Cannot be resolved

I added various dependencies to pom file but still bundle is not changed to active state and hence i cant invoke this service from my component jsp page. Please help.

Comment: Installed state is not an error. It just means the bundle is installed...

Comment: You have given essentially zero information for anybody who wants to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the scenarios its the problem with you internal network . Maven will try to download the jars but it will be failing .

try adding a lower jar version dependency in pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-jsr166e</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can download the jar directly and put it in you local maven folder 
C:\Users\xxx.m2\repository and then use install/update to install the jar.

Once you successfully install the jar trying refreshing the bundle

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I tried with<Export-Package>.... </Export-Package> and all the "cannot be resolved issues" are resolved but there is new error "sun.misc -- Cannot be resolved and overwritten by Boot Delegation"

Comment: Can i invoke this service from my component jsp page only if bundle state is "active"? Do i need a ServiceID to be generated for my bundle

Comment: What do you mean you "tried it with <ExportPackage>..". What package did you export? You have given essentially zero information for anybody who wants to help you.